# Authentication in Django Custom Model

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-models

I have a model ApplicantRegister which has various fields. I want to register applicant after fill up the required information. After Registration and Mail Verification I want to logged in applicant through email and password. But I am getting Log in Details Wrong even though i submitted right information. Can't we use django built in authenticate method in custom model ?

models.py

```
class ApplicantRegister(models.Model):

    applicant_name_in_english = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    applicant_name_in_bengali = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    
    father_name_in_english = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    father_name_in_bengali = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    
    mother_name_in_english = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    mother_name_in_bengali = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    
    marital_status = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    
    spouse_name_in_english = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    spouse_name_in_bengali = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    present_address_in_english = models.TextField()
    present_address_in_bengali = models.TextField()
    
    permanent_address_in_english = models.TextField()
    permanent_address_in_bengali = models.TextField()
    
    religion = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    
    home_district = models.CharField(max_length=30,
            choices=DISTRICT_CHOICES)
    
    national_id = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    confirm_phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    confirm_email = models.EmailField()
    
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    confirm_password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    
    applicant_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='applicantImages/',
            validators=[validate_file_size([200]),
            validate_file_extension, validate_image_dimension([300],
            [300])])
    
    applicant_signature = \
        models.ImageField(upload_to='applicantSignature/',
                          validators=[validate_file_size([100]),
                          validate_file_extension,
                          validate_image_dimension([300], [80])])
    
    reference_1 = models.TextField()
    reference_2 = models.TextField()
    
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.applicant_name_in_english
```

views.py

```
def registerView(request):

    applicant_form = ApplicantRegisterModelForm()
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        applicant_form = ApplicantRegisterModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    
        if applicant_form.is_valid():
            applicant = applicant_form.save(commit=False)
            applicant.is_active = False
            applicant.save()
    
            current_site_info = get_current_site(request)  
    
            mail_subject = 'The Activation link has been sent to your email address, Please Activate Your Account'  
    
            message = render_to_string('registration_app/acc_active_email.html', {  
                'user': applicant,  
                'domain': current_site_info.domain,  
           'uid':urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(applicant.pk)),  
              'token':account_activation_token.make_token(applicant),  
            })  
            to_email = applicant_form.cleaned_data.get('email') 
    
            email = EmailMessage(  
                      mail_subject, message, to=[to_email]  
            )  
            email.send()  
            print('email sent')
          
            return HttpResponse('Please proceed confirm your email address to complete the registration')
        else:
            print('Errors in data')
            print(applicant_form.errors)
    
    data = {
        'applicant_form':applicant_form,
    }
    
    return render(request, 'registration_app/register.html', context=data)
    
    
def activate(request, uidb64, token):  
        
    try:  
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))  
        applicant = ApplicantRegister.objects.get(pk=uid)  
        print(uid, applicant)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, ApplicantRegister.DoesNotExist):  
        applicant = None  
        
    if applicant is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(applicant, token):  
        applicant.is_active = True  
        applicant.save()  
        return HttpResponse('Thank you for your email confirmation. Now you can login your account.')  
    else:  
        return HttpResponse('Activation link is invalid!')  
    
    
    
def login_page(request):
    return render(request, 'registration_app/login.html', context={})
    
def applicant_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST.get('email') 
        # username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
    
        # print(username, password)
    
        applicant = authenticate(username=email, password=password)
    
        print(applicant)
        if applicant:
            if applicant.is_active:
                login(request, applicant)
    
                # To change the urlpatterns we are using this method
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home_page_app:home'))
    
                # if we return using render function then urlpatterns does not change that's why we need to use previous method
                # return render(request, 'registration_app/index.html', context={})
    
                # this method also does not change urlpatterns
                # return index(request)
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Account is not active')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Log In details are wrong')
      
    else:
        # return render(request, 'registration_app/login.html', context={})
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('registration_app:login'))
    
@login_required
def applicant_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home_page_app:home'))
```

login.html

```
<form action="{% url 'registration_app:applicant-login' %}" method="POST">
  
    {% csrf_token %}
    
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input class="form-control w-50" type="email" name="email" id="id_email" placeholder="Enter your email" required>
    
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input class="form-control w-50" type="password" name="password" id="id_password" placeholder="Enter Your Password" required>
    
    <br>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Log In">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to extend and customize the base user model for authentication but you have to follow the Django documentation [Extending the existing User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) [Substituting a custom User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) [Using a custom user model when starting a project](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project)

These three link should help you.